# multiple SQL queries stored as vb.net variable

Tags: sql, vb.net, variables, ms-access-2007

I know there are a few other posts about putting sql results into a vb.net variable but I just couldn't wrap my head around how they did it and how I could do it in my project.

So what I'm trying to do is query my database for 4 different values and then display each value in a certain part of the form. I was going to store the each value into a variable and then do an textbox1.text = i

Updated code for 10/5/2014

```
 Private Sub LBmembers_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LBmembers.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim i As String = LBmembers.SelectedItem
    Dim dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    Dim dbSource = "Data Source= C:\members.mdb "
    Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT StartTime, EndTime, ShipCode, CycleTime, WorkPercent, Share FROM tblMembers WHERE Member = @ID;"
    Using con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(dbProvider & dbSource)
        Using cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(SqlQuery, con)
            con.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = i
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.Read() Then
                    TBtimestart.Text = reader.ToString(0)
                    TBtimeend.Text = reader.ToString(1)
                    Dim j = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ToString(2))
                    TBtimecycle.Text = reader.GetInt32(3).ToString
                    TBmemberpercent.Text = reader.GetInt32(4)
                    TBmembershare.Text = reader.GetInt32(5)
                    If j = 1 Then
                        RBpro.Checked = True
                    ElseIf j = 2 Then
                        RBret.Checked = True
                    ElseIf j = 3 Then
                        RBcov.Checked = True
                    ElseIf j = 4 Then
                        RBskiff.Checked = True
                    ElseIf j = 5 Then
                        RBmack.Checked = True
                    ElseIf j = 6 Then
                        RBhulk.Checked = True
                    Else
                        RBpro.Checked = False
                        RBret.Checked = False
                        RBcov.Checked = False
                        RBskiff.Checked = False
                        RBmack.Checked = False
                        RBhulk.Checked = False
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
            End Using
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

The exception

InvalidCastException was unhandled Specified cast is not valid.

Pops up on the line TBtimecycle.text = reader.GetInt32(3).ToString

The reader is also reading "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader" when I insert the test code "TBgrossisk.Text = reader.ToString()" into the using statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully to the syntax of the [SELECT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) statement you will see that you can request any column of the table with just one query.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LBmembers.SelectedIndexChanged
    if string.IsNullOrWitheSpace(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Select an item from the Listbox")
    End If

    Dim member As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem
    Dim dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    Dim dbSource = "Data Source= C:\members.mdb "
    Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT StartTime, EndTime, ShipCode, CycleTime " & _ 
                             "FROM tblMembers WHERE Member = @ID;"
    Using con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(dbProvider & dbSource)
        Using cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(SqlQuery, con)
            con.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = member
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
               if reader.Read() Then
                  TextBox1.Text = reader.GetString(0)
                  TextBox2.Text = reader.GetString(1)
                  Dim j = reader.GetInt32(2)
                  If j = 1 Then
                      Radio1.Checked = True
                  ElseIf j = 2 Then
                      Radio2.Checked = True
                  ElseIf j = 3 Then
                      Radio3.Checked = True
                  ElseIf j = 4 Then
                      Radio4.Checked = True
                  ElseIf j = 5 Then
                      Radio5.Checked = True
                  ElseIf j = 6 Then
                      Radio6.Checked = True
                  Else
                      Exit Sub
                  End If
                  TextBox4.Text = reader.GetInt32(3).ToString()
               Else
                  MessageBox.Show("The search for '" & member & "' doesn't find any data")
               End If
           End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Instead of using ExecuteScalar that returns just the first column of the first row retrieved you could use an `OleDbDataReader` returned by the method `ExecuteReader`. This object allows to access the various column in the current record using an index (or the column name). Read more about [OleDbDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) in MSDN

Comment: "No value given for one or more required parameters"  on line "Using reader = cmd.executereader"

Comment: Are you sure that your tblMembers has these 5 columns? They should be exactly named as Column1 to Column5.

Comment: I omitted their proper names for security reasons but yes it does have 5 columns. Column 1 is the member's name(which is unique and the primary key) Would I get the error if say there was no data in columns 2-4?

Comment: No, you will get a different error. This one usually means that the Access engine cannot find a column or a table with the name you have written in the query. So, for example, if your column1 is named IDMember then use that name in the query and likewise for the other columns. Please update your question with the real names, so I could try to update my answer

Comment: Wow I just caught my error the first column in the select statement is backwards

Comment: _StartTime_ or _TimeStart_? remember? Exact names... Hope it helps because now I am going to sleep. It's 1 past midnight here. Bye

Comment: Although now im getting "Specified cast is not valid" exceptions

Comment: Changed the type of the parameter @ID to VarWChar and added a missing 32 to GetInt32. Fixed also the reading of the third field (ShipCode is a string) and of the fourth field (CycleTime is an Integer)

Comment: ok but when all this code runs the reader reads "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader" as a result of the query still think it might be because none of the fields have any data yet as you need to select a member from the listbox in the form before setting their data.

Comment: This is just annoying because I can open access and create a new entry into the table
"Test, 2014-10-04 22:09:18, 2014-10-04 22:09:19, 5, 111
and then run the same sql statement that runs in the code 
SELECT StartTime, EndTime, ShipCode, CycleTime FROM tblMembers WHERE Member = 'Test'; and it'll output the right data.

Comment: Well this is just expected. If there is no item selected or the search (`WHERE member = @ID`) doesn't find a suitable record there is nothing to show, but just a warning to your user. Added a couple of messages to the answer

Comment: yet after I enter suitable data in the fields and try to retrieve the data using the program it yields the same results as if there was no data so i'm not sure that's the case here

Comment: Sorry but I can't help from here. The commands seems to be ok. If you are willing to share the database I could try here some testing

Comment: how would I share it with you its just a blank database used for storing data while the program is open.

Comment: Well you could add a single record manually in your db then zip the MDB file and upload on some sharing drive like GDrive, OneDrive or Dropbox. Then put the link here.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5h7w5yr8u7f3j8p/members.mdb?dl=0
The values for the WorkPercent and Share are dummy values percent may or may not have a decimal and the share will probably be much larger say between 1 and 1000000000.00

Comment: I have changed two things. The variable SqlQuery1 is just SqlQuery and the field ShipCode is an integer, so I have changed the reading using GetInt32. A part from this I can load the record present in the test database. But you should get an exception message on that code.

Comment: I have updated the code. InvalidCastException was unhandled Specified cast is not valid. is the exception thrown at TBtimecycle.Text = reader.GetInt32(3).ToString

Comment: I rearranged where the If statement is so it reads all the rows from the query before running if statement.

Comment: so its basicly telling me that GetInt32 is not the same as an integer on the access database...
What if I change GetInt32 to just GetValue, I get a DBnull to type string is not valid. wonder if i can make it so it converts that to a store able value...

Comment: well I can change GetInt32 to GetValue(3).ToString which stops the exceptions but now its back to outputing a single character of the line "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader" will have to do more research

Comment: Interesting so I wrote some test code like: TBgrossisk.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString and basicly outputed the reader values to different larger text boxes and it works find. Still can't get the if statement to work with the j variable.

Comment: Well it's all complete and working. I changed the data type of the ShipCode to string and then ran the if statement that way. Also "If Not IsDBNull(reader.GetValue(2)) Then" before determining which radio box to check to remove any DBnull exceptions.